# Can't find where to modify <html> attrbitutes

Tags: plugin-development, wp-head

I am trying to create a simple function that adds or edits data in the `<html>`. Basically, before the server response is sent, I want to find where this piece of html is written at the top level of the page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
```

And based on certain criteria, add a new property & value that tag.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" myprop1="val1" myprop2="val2">
```

Is there an action or filter I can hook into, at it's earliest to modify this? Most likely using regex? Side note, I understand how it break validation, but I need this for my purposes.

**Update**

To answer couple questions:

- I know I can insert variables inside of html tags with just PHP. The problem is I can't find where in the WP core the actual starting `html` tag is being generated so I can replace or modify what's being generated.
- This will be in a plugin, theme independent, where the html tag is unknown, but 99% of the time it will be the standard output from Wordpress
- I can't use the header.php in a theme, as I would like this to work on whatever theme is installed. Is this specific tag always generated from the theme? Any way to override theme generated  tag (if user specifies this) within a plugin?

Comment: Hi Nathan this isn't really related to WordPress, you can insert variables inside HTML tags with PHP.

Comment: is the `<html>` head always going to be the same before your changes? or is this for a plugin where the `html` tag is unknown? If you know the html is always going to be the same you should be able to use buffer/string replace to do this.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't edit the theme's `header.php`? I don't know why you think you need regex. Maybe you do but a good answer isn't possible without know what you are trying to to (and this is on its way to being closed as off-topic so hopefully the additional information makes the question WordPress specific.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't edit your header.php, or would prefer not to, most decent WordPress themes should have (and certainly any that pass theme review to be in the official repository)

```
<html <?php language_attributes();?> >
```

in the opening html tag in the header.php template.

There is a filter in the `language_attributes()` function that allows plugins/child themes to modify the ouput, like so:

```
function wpa89133( $output ) {
    $output .= ' myprop1="val1" myprop2="val2"';
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'language_attributes', 'wpa89133' );
```